# How to remove a dict objects(letter) that remain in another str?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Suppose I have this dictionary:

```
x = {'a':2, 'b':5, 'g':7, 'a':3, 'h':8}`
```

And this input string:

```
y = 'agb'
```

I want to delete the keys of `x` that appear in `y`, such as, if my input is as above, output should be:

```
{'h':8, 'a':3}
```

My current code is here:

```
def x_remove(x,word):
   x1 = x.copy()   # copy the input dict
      for i in word:   # iterate all the letters in str           
          if i in x1.keys():
              del x1[i]    
   return x1
```

But when the code runs, it removes all existing key similar as letters in word. But i want though there is many keys similar as letter in word , it only delete one key not every

wheres my wrong, i got that maybe but Just explain me how can i do that without using del function

Comment: You have a duplicate key in your dictionary `x`

Comment: Dicts don't allow duplicate keys. After all, what would `x['a']` be if there were two entries for key `'a'`?

Comment: Also, never do `thing in some_dict.keys()`. That builds a list of keys and does a slow linear search through the list to find the element. Always use `thing in some_dict`.

Comment: Your code behaves as expected (although it might behave different than what *you* expected). Since dictionaries can't have duplicated keys to begin with, you end up with `{'h': 8}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but try this instead:

```
def x_remove(input_dict, word):
    output_dict = input_dict.copy()

    for letter in word:        
        if letter in output_dict:
            del output_dict[letter]

    return output_dict
```

For example:

```
In [10]: x_remove({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}, 'ac')
Out[10]: {'b': 2}
```

One problem was your indentation. Indentation matters in Python, and is used the way `{` and `}` and `;` are in other languages. Another is the way you were checking to see if each letter was in the list; you want `if letter in output_dict` since `in` on a `dict()` searches keys.

It's also easier to see what's going on when you use descriptive variable names.

We can also skip the `del` entirely and make this more Pythonic, using a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
def x_remove(input_dict, word):
    return {key: value for key, value in input_dict if key not in word}
```

This will still implicitly create a shallow copy of the list (without the removed elements) and return it. This will be more performant as well.

As stated in the comments, all keys in dictionaries are unique. There can only ever be one key named `'a'` or `b`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary must have unique keys.  You may use list of tuples for your data instead.

`x = [('a',2), ('b',5), ('g',7), ('a',3), ('h',8)]`

Following code then deletes the desired entries:

```
for letter in y:
    idx = 0
    for item in x.copy():   
        if item[0] == letter:
            del x[idx]
            break
        idx += 1
```

Result:

```
>>> x
[('a', 3), ('h', 8)]
```

Comment: Thanks for ur ans.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement like

```
def remove_(x,y)
    for i in y:
        try:
           del x[i]
        except:
           pass
    return x
```

Inputs `x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}` and `y = 'ac'`.

**Output**

```
{'b': 2}
```